# What are efficient ways to enhance the security of MD5 hashes?

Tags: security, cryptography, md5, hash

I mean actually making it hard to exploit even if the user has chosen a relatively simple password(s)? I can't think of anything besides using additional cryptographic functions.

Comment: Use a different algorithm. Why do you *have* to stick with MD5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

- A cryptographically stronger hashing algorithm.
- [Salts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)
- [Key strengthening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_strengthening) (e.g. [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29#Blowfish-based_scheme) / [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) / [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2))

Use **all** these techniques for the best security.

The last is not particularly efficient in terms of performance, but that's deliberate. The problem with most commonly used cryptographic hash functions is that they are designed to be *fast* to compute, which means that they are also fast to crack if the password is a dictionary word. The idea of key strengthening is to make the algorithm so slow to compute that even a weak password will take a long time to crack.

Comment: Wow no mention of the prefixing attack?  You're not going to get a +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think, read ;) (and ask on SO) You'll want to salt passwords with their own individual salt so that the same password won't result in the same hash

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to add a salt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) to the password you're going to hash. Anyway, be aware that there'll always be some risk associated with hashing a password, take a look at this article http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002095.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Salt isn't immune to brute-forcing or dictionary attack but it will do for now I guess.

Comment: @stokkseyri _nothing_ is immune to brute force - if they try the correct password (eventually) how can you tell the difference between an attacker and an end user??? The idea of cryptography is to make brute force the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Leave crypto security, and analysis of it, to the experts, and just use a better crypto function.

Comment: I'm simply looking for methods I have not come across yet, I know I'm not a expert nor can contribute in a significant way.

Answer (score 0):

Not using MD5 for hashing passwords. The same goes for about any hash function that's optimized for throughput. The idea of SHA1 and MD5 is, that you can generate a compact representation of virtually unlimited amounts of data, so that you can check it's integrity and also sign it cryptographically.

The idea of hashing passwords is, that you cannot retrieve the password from the hash. However most passwords are shorter than their hash, and implementing a brute force or dictionary attack is trivial. So given a hash, the used hash function one can implement the check logic locally -- possibly on a massive parallel computer, think GPU -- and break passwords reasonably fast.

What you actually want to do is using a hash function, that's so computationally intense that hashing takes so much time, that even attempting a brute force attack on a 4 character password took hours.

Answer (score -1):

Just add some salt to the user entered password.

```
$salt = 'random string';
md5(sha1(md5($salt . $_POST['password'])));
```

Almost no way that result can be cracked.

Comment: exploited?  I think you mean cracked.  And yes,  a dictionary attack is easy to perform against this,  its called  a FOR LOOP.

Comment: If the structure/settings of the salt is compromised, or it'd take quite a while I imagine.